# Save canvas as image-file, but canvas contains an image

Tags: javascript, canvas

**Problem:**
I want to download a `canvas` as an image file (jpg/png).

This will work unless i don't use `drawImage`

to put an image on the `canvas` before i download it.

**Question:**
I can download the image with right-click "save as",
but is there a way to download it with a `button` or `link`?

*(My idea is a canvas where ppl can draw over images and save them.)*

**Fiddle** without image (dl works): https://jsfiddle.net/Lawgqfwo/

**Fiddle** with image (dl does not work): https://jsfiddle.net/o5m4m8xp/

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


// var img = new Image();
// img.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg";
// ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);


// download button
var button = document.getElementById('btn-download');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  button.href = dataURL;
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<a href="#" class="button" id="btn-download" download="meinBild.png">Download</a>
```

Comment: Two problems. (1) You must give img time to load with `img.onload`, (2) You cannot use `.toDataURL` after drawing a cross-origin image on the canvas.

Comment: Ok, that helps me out. Now i have to find a different approach.